# QT Candlestick Chart with real-time data

Tags: qtcharts

There is a cool [Candlestick Chart](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtcharts-overview.html#candlestick-charts) in QT6.

[image]

and there is an example on how to add data into the chart with QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtCharts 2.2

ChartView {
    title: "Candlestick series"
    width: 800
    height: 600
    theme: ChartView.ChartThemeLight
    legend.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom
    antialiasing: true

    CandlestickSeries {
        name: "Acme Ltd."
        increasingColor: "green"
        decreasingColor: "red"

        CandlestickSet { timestamp: 1435708800000; open: 6.90; high: 6.94; low: 5.99; close: 6.60 }
        CandlestickSet { timestamp: 1435795200000; open: 6.69; high: 6.69; low: 6.69; close: 6.69 }
        CandlestickSet { timestamp: 1436140800000; open: 4.85; high: 6.23; low: 4.85; close: 6.00 }
        CandlestickSet { timestamp: 1436227200000; open: 5.89; high: 6.15; low: 3.77; close: 5.69 }
        CandlestickSet { timestamp: 1436313600000; open: 4.64; high: 4.64; low: 2.54; close: 2.54 }
    }
}
```

but what if the data is real-time and the last candle can vary and new candles can be added? Is it possible to modify the candles (chart data) without a flickering?

For example, [CandlestickSeries](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qtcharts-candlestickseries.html#signals) has `add/remove` but not `changed` signals.

Comment: CandlestickSeries has at(index) method and you can get CandlestickSet QML item and change the high and low property. or change insert a new CandlestickSet at the end of the series.

Comment: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qml-qtcharts-candlestickseries.html#at-method

Comment: Yes, I was able to do `series.at(2).open = 3`. `QCandlestickSet` has `openChanged` signal and the chart updates automatically.

Comment: so , your problem solved ?

Comment: Probably I misunderstood something, but `ChartView` does not refresh when I add `CandlestickSet` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69608695/chartview-does-not-refresh-when-candlestickset-is-added